# What is the alternative in JPA for a preparedStatement inside of the other in JDBC?

Tags: jpa, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
 PreparedStatement pstmt1=conn.prepareStatement("select * from vehicles");
         ResultSet rs1=pstmt1.executeQuery();
         while(rs1.next()){
         int id=rs1.getInt("id");

         PreparedStatement pstmt2=conn.prepareStatement("select lat,lng from        vehicles where vehicle_id=123 and id=?");

         pstmt2.setInt(1,(id+1));
         //out.println("here i am");
         ResultSet rs2=pstmt2.executeQuery();
        double lat1=Math.toRadians(rs1.getDouble("lat"));
        double lng1=Math.toRadians(rs1.getDouble("lng"));

        while (rs2.next()){

         lat2=Math.toRadians(rs2.getDouble("lat"));
         lng2=Math.toRadians(rs2.getDouble("lng"));

        }
```

Actually, i am trying to calculate the total distance covered in km by a vehicle throughout the day. For this, i am using each latitude and longitude point as the source and destination for each small distances and at last adding them, i get the total sum. I am using JPA and could not figure out how to use this concept in the above code in JPA. Can anybody help me out? It would be a great pleasure. :)

Comment: No idea what that means. In JPA you can use JPQL queries or SQL queries. And the problem is?

Comment: I don't see the reason for the two nested statements in the first place. Why don't you just loop over the result of `select id, lat, lng from vehicles where vehicle_id = 123`? That would be a **lot** more efficient

Comment: It is to be nested so that i can query the latitude and longitude of the vehicles with id of the vehicle in this manner--> [1,2],[2,3],[3,4] and so  I can calculate the distance between 1 and 2, between 2 and 3 and so on. and each time i should add the distance to an arraylist, at last will add all the elements of the arraylist  to find out the total distance travelled by the vehicle.